# Django getting model data where something > something else

Tags: python, django, models

With Django I have this model:

```
class downloads(models.Model):
date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
ip = models.ForeignKey(IPaddress)
partnum = models.ForeignKey(partnum)
user = models.ForeignKey(userinfo)
filename = models.CharField(max_length=128)
issueId = models.ForeignKey(issueInfo)
```

What I need to do is to get data from that table where the date is > date 1 and < date2

I know if I was using PHP I could query the db to do something like `select * from downloads where date > date1 and date < date2` which would ofc give me a dataset to iterate through, How do I go about this using Django?

I am going to take a wild stab in the dark and ask is it something like this:

```
d = downloads.objects.get('Where date > date1 and date < date2')
```

or

```
d = downloads.objects.get(date=>date1,date<=date2)
```

I am very new to python and Django (started to learn it last week...) and any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the quick replys - worked out the answer to my new question

Comment: why is this question being downvoted .. I don't get it

Comment: `downloads` needs to be capitalized, or none of the following answers will work. I should also mention that all Django DB classes are capitalized, usually with camel case if the table name is more than one word long (e.g., `user_activity` defaults to `UserActivity` upon running `python manage.py inspectdb`.)

Comment: One more thing: since you're new to both Python and Django, I would recommend looking at the Python documentation and learning Python first, then moving on to check out the Django book @ djangobook.com/en/2.0 .

Comment: i am aware of the camel caps Edwin, this wont be my final code i am in a position where i am being forced to do something fast for work so dont have the luxury of learning python first :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Django ORM then do the following:

```
downloads = Downloads.objects.filter(date__range=(dat1, date2))
```

or

```
downloads = Downloads.objects.filter(date__gt=date1, date__lt=date2)
```

This will filter your objects accordingly. `__gt` means "greater than" and `__lt` means "less than".

Read the documentation for further clarification:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Comment: you can also use `__gte` for "greater or equal than" and `__lte` for "less or equal than"

Answer (score 2):

Take a proper look at Django's docs, they're really good and comprehensive.

In your case you should check the [docs on querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference), as you hardly write any SQL directly, but usually use Django's ORM.

In your case I'd consider using the [`range` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range).

```
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at that :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

```
d = Downloads.objects.filter(date__gt= dateParam1, date__lt= dateParam2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two datetime objects, and then you can do:

```
Downloads.objects.filter(date__gt=startdate, date__lt=enddate)
```